How can I check if my M.2 slot and BIOS has functionality needed for M.2 Coral TPU?
What Unix command could help identify if an M.2 slot is compatible with an M.2 Coral TPU?
Are there general recommendations what firmware/BIOS settings to enable/disable for M.2 Coral TPU?
I have

Coral M.2 Accelerator with Dual Edge TPU
minirout.com CM-M1 Mini PC.

The Mini PC has two M.2 headers:

M.2 2230 E-Key（WIFI）: PCIe + USB Protocol
M.2 2242 M-Key（SSD）: PCIe X2/SATA Protocol

I removed the WiFi card and inserted Coral TPU. However the system no longer boots when the card is inserted (auto shut down after a couple seconds).
ChatGPT thinks that the M.2 ports are compatible but that I might only have 1X PCIe protocol.
I believe I should be able get one of the two TPUs working with this setup.
I confirmed that the card works as it is recognized in my laptop when I replace its WiFi card with the TPU.
I searched for EFI/BOOT update on manufacturers website and I have current version.
The AMI firmware has lots of options and its tough to figure out if changing any of them will solve my problem.

You read the specifications. Take M.2 E-key (with two PCIe Gen2 x1 lanes) for instance. It’s a PCIe M.2 device. Provided the size of the device will work then it’s compatible. The size of course for that product is “22 mm x 30 mm (M.2-2230-D3-E)” As for not turning on, it’s probably try to draw, to much power suspect that m.2 slot isn’t actually PCIe Gen2
